# в чем отличие alias в bash от alias в git?

Tags: git, bash, консоль, alias

В чем отличие alias в bash(в терминале) от alias в git?

Некоторое уточнение: alias в терминале применяется ко всей операционной системе, конкретному пользователю, всем пользователям операционной системы?
alias в git применяется для локальных пользователей репозитория, для конкретной папки, для пользователей удаленного репозитория?

PS. Тут я понимаю, что можно задать alias git в терминале системы, не в самом git. В системе Linux. Не совсем еще понятно, в Windows терминал git это не терминал системы, а терминал git? Или это эмуляция некоторого терминала?

Comment: alias в bash не имеет никакого отношения к alias в git, а alias в git не имеет никакого отношения к alias в bash. Просто реализация похожей функциональности в двух разных никак не связанных программах

Answer (score 1):

Нет никаких отличий. И там и там алиас - сокращение для консольной команды.